# My USB flash drive cannot be read, the OS asks me if I'm to format it now

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I'm using a Sandisk 4 GB flash drive on a Windows XP machine and just found it cannot be read anymore. The OS keeps telling me the disk cannot be read and if I'm to reformat it now. I have some important files on the disk, so I dare not to reformat it, nor have I tried any data recovery software, because I'm just not so sure of it.

Here are some background information which may help clarify things a bit more:

(1) I've repeatedly written and rewritten the flash drive during the last two days. I think it's getting to its full storage capacity.

(2) The computer has been suddenly shut down (I don't know the exact cause) for two times when the USB flash drive is connected to the computer.

While I'm aware of I'm not alone running into this problem and there are couple of tentative solutions on the internet, I still feel like your good tips and suggestions to encourge me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I heard good things about testdisk and several data recovery softs, but not sure which one of them is good and suitable for me. Thanks.

Comment: Testdisk is probably your best bet for recovering the data on the drive.  Once you have saved what it can recover, you can format the drive again and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks,techturtle,I'm working on it. As you can see in the screen captures above, it looks like nothings has been found, what shall I do next? Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell what steps you did to get there, but it seems like you had Testdisk create a partition.  Can't say I've ever done that.  Usually you just have to tell it what kind of partition you had (EXT, FAT32, NTFS, etc) and it will scan the drive for you and save anything it finds to your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks turtle. I've tried photorec instead and have retrieved all but one folder. That sounds good, doesn't it?